# Variable + Number to Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am currently confused any help would be great.

I am currently trying to press a button to add 40 to `sales` but in order to add 40 I need the current number of sales so I used a fetch array to output this number and I see it as '40' so I set it to a variable then tried $varible + 40 set the number. This does not seem to be working I check online and anyhelp would be awesome!

```
    $query = "SELECT `sales` FROM `sales`";

    if ($result=mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            print_r($row);
    }


    if ($_POST['update']) {


        echo 'Updating...';


        $query="UPDATE `sales` SET `sales` = '$row+40' WHERE `sales`.`id` = 1";

        mysqli_query($link, $query);

        echo '<br>Successfully Updated';

 } else {

            echo 'Unsuccessful';

}
```

Comment: the question is unclear. Can you update your post to included the HTML for this?

Comment: you've an answer now, see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the query goes in MySQL you don't need to do two separate ones to add to existing data. The query would go as follows:

```
UPDATE `sales` SET `sales` = `sales` + 40 WHERE `sales`.`id` = 1;
```

So your code would look like this...

```
if($_POST['update']) {
    echo 'Updating...';
    $query = "UPDATE `sales` SET `sales` = `sales` + 40 WHERE `sales`.`id` = 1";
    mysqli_query($link, $query);
    echo '<br>Successfully Updated';
} else {
    echo 'Unsuccessful';
}
```

By the way, the reason your code is failing right now is because `$row` is an array. You would have to access a certain key in that array to get the data you want out of it. Right now you're trying to get the sum of 40 and an array object.

Comment: What do you mean? The code is just not adding $Row.40

Comment: You don't need to query the database for the existing '`$row`' data. You can just use one query (the query I gave you above) when that button is pressed to add 40 to that data.

Comment: @Nydigov I updated my answer to further explain it.